# how to remove some link text?

Tags: jquery, menubar

i have some index.php page..
after download jquery drop down menu,the link text like "no back link" always appear..it disturbing my page..how to remove it??
how if it comes from installed file which consist of css file and js file??
what part that must i change?

```
<img src="bannersketch.png" border="0">
<div id="menu">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="index.php" class="parent"><span>Home</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>Inspection Report</span></a>
            <div>
                <ul>
                        <li><a href="inspection_report1.php#Tabs-1" class="parent"><span>Inspection Report</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="inspection_report1.php#Tabs-2"><span>Input Data</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Statistics</span></a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#"><span>Contacts</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[alt text http://img594.imageshack.us/img594/8752/screenshot3r.png](http://img594.imageshack.us/img594/8752/screenshot3r.png)

Comment: Will be useful to see your Jquery code and output html.

Comment: There's nothing here to indicate where that link might be coming from. It's not in the HTML you provide, so it's either in some other HTML on the page, the Javascript included, or an extension you have installed.

Comment: how if that come from my installe file??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found the answer to this problem. We must put the copyright inside our page, like:

```
<div id="copyright">
    Copyright &copy; 2010 <a href="http://apycom.com/">Apycom jQuery Menus</a>
</div>
```

and if you don't want to show that link text, you just hide it in CSS.

Comment: ...and that will surely suck out all your SEO points that link appears in, LOL

Comment: Ha, thanks... this little link bothered me alot ! But for such an awesome free drop down menu, the least I could do was give them the credits on my webpage... :)

Answer (score 4):

Remove  this from page

```
<div id="copyright">Copyright &copy; 2011 <a href="http://apycom.com/">Apycom jQuery Menus</a></div>
```

then put this anywhere in the page. This is the best way to remove apycom.com backlink

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("body div:last").remove();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

SEO-friendly solution:

```
<script>
document.write('<div style="display:none;"><a href="http://apycom.com/">jQuery Menu by Apycom</a></div>');
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think no need to add any code... just follow this thing: open menu.js file , find for apycom  it will show you /** apycom menu ****************/ commented line. just comment the code under this commented line. .. best luck. this worked form me.

This will save of additional code execution and unnecessary script loading while page load.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
 $('a[href="http://apycom.com/"]').parent().parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this after the HTML tag to hide it

```
<div style="visibility: hidden">
 <br />
 <a href="http://apycom.com/">Apycom jQuery Menus</a><br />
</div>
```

just < infront

Answer (score 0):

Add this code at the bottom of the menu.js:

```
$(function () { $("body").find("a[href='http://apycom.com/']").parents("div:first").detach(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution is simple,
the code of "menu.js" is obfuscated. So that, de-obfuscate it.

1. open the file, look for the code under /** apycom menu ****************/, copy it all and de-ofuscate it. there are deofuscators online. http://jsbeautifier.org/
2. look for this line "return f.b(k, f.a(s))" and alert it "alert(f.b(k, f.a(s)))";
   ...
   alert(f.b(k, f.a(s)));
   return f.b(k, f.a(s))
   ...
3. copy all text alerted
4. replace all the code from this jquery function for the alerted one

jQuery(function () ...

5.comment or erase the function where code validates if there is a link present pointing to apycom

6.that's all folks!!!

with these steps you will get all the code for your own